# How to overlay a view over another view in android?

Tags: android, xml, view

I am trying to make a view overlay another view. Here is my XML:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonGroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

        <RadioButton
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="true"
            android:contentDescription="ZONA"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_back_selector"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tabZoneHome"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/home_tab_zone"
            android:gravity="center"/>


        <RadioButton
            android:button="@null"
            android:contentDescription="VISITADAS"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_back_selector"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tabVisitedHome"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/home_tab_visited"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:button="@null"
            android:contentDescription="SUGERENCIAS"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_back_selector"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tabSuggestionsHome"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/home_tab_suggestions"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="false" />

    </RadioGroup>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButtonGroup" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/quickview_top_gradient"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"           
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the RadioGroup to go above the frame_container but so far no luck. I have tried the following in java:

```
  RadioGroup myButton = (RadioGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.radioButtonGroup);
  RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.test);
  layout.bringChildToFront(AdsRecycler.this);
  layout.invalidate();
```

However nothing is changed the. The Radio Group does not overlay the frame_container. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**, how do you expect the the views to be over one another when you specified:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/radioButtonGroup"
```

This will always shift the `FrameLayout` below the radio buttons. Remove this line.

**Second** android lays items in order. So your radio buttons is the base layer then goes the FrameLayout and so on. You want to first put the background (FrameLayout), then the `RadioGroup`:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout/>

    <RadioGroup>
        ...
    </RadioGroup>

    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Oh my god ... I am so ashamed ... man I hate when I miss things like this :( Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just move you RadioGroup below FrameLayout in your XML.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButtonGroup" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonGroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

        <RadioButton
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="true"
            android:contentDescription="ZONA"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_back_selector"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tabZoneHome"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/home_tab_zone"
            android:gravity="center"/>


        <RadioButton
            android:button="@null"
            android:contentDescription="VISITADAS"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_back_selector"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tabVisitedHome"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/home_tab_visited"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:button="@null"
            android:contentDescription="SUGERENCIAS"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_back_selector"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tabSuggestionsHome"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/home_tab_suggestions"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="false" />

    </RadioGroup>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/quickview_top_gradient"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"           
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative layouts arrange items with respect to the positions of other items and, as far as i know, do not allow overlaying. Use a frame layout instead.

Answer (score -1):

You are not using frame layout correctly. place radio group and image view as child of the frame layout and you can remove the relative layout which is not required